# iOS continue deceleration to top

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I want to achieve following effect: when scroll view decelerates and iOS tries to stop it at 20 points Y offset (for example), instead of stopping it should continue decelerate until reaches zero offset with deceleration velocity. I tried to set offset with `setContentOffset:animated:`, but obviously this method doesn't use needed velocity and scroll view just jumps to zero offset. How can I make it work? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your scroll view a delegate and implement [`scrollViewWillEndDragging(_:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619385-scrollviewwillenddragging) to change the target content offset as explained in the documentation.